# How to render umlauts with jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, diacritics

I am trying to render some basic umlauts with jinja2.

**test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<h3>Umlauts: ä ü ö</h3>
```

**Result.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<h3>Umlauts: Ã¤ Ã¼ Ã¶</h3>
```

**My code**

```
from jinja2 import Template

file = open("test.html")
data = file.read()
Template(data).stream().dump("index.html")
```

Now I don't understand how to get jinja to process the umlauts correctly. How can I do this? I am using stream, because in my actual usecase I am providing some data to fill in, then dumping it to an html to be displayed.

EDIT: Is what I want even possible? As I understand this from [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.environment.TemplateStream.dump) it is not?

> It is not possible to use Jinja2 to process non-Unicode data. The
>   reason for this is that Jinja2 uses Unicode already on the language
>   level. For example Jinja2 treats the non-breaking space as valid
>   whitespace inside expressions which requires knowledge of the encoding
>   or operating on an Unicode string.

Comment: You almost certainly want to specify an encoding here, as detailed in [the documentation for `dump`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.environment.TemplateStream.dump).

Comment: This did not help.

Comment: What about `<head> and <body>`?

Comment: Nope. This also didn't work.

Comment: How are you examining the output file? This looks as if you are simply using a viewer configured for Latin-1 to look at text which is actually completely proper UTF-8. See perhaps also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) which explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python3 you can specify the encoding with `open`.

```
from jinja2 import Template

file = open("test.html", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data = file.read()
Template(data).stream().dump('index.html')
```

For Python2 you can use the io module to specify encoding.

```
import io

file = io.open("test.html", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Aaah there was my problem, thanks, I had the feeling it was a problem with jinja.

Comment: @Hakaishin: `dump()` uses `UTF-8` by default when writing, so yes, your issue was with the input. If you are using Python 3, the `open()` function **is the same thing** as the `io.open()` function, and you simply forgot to specify the correct encoding (at which point a system default is used instead).

Comment: @Hakaishin: In fact, I'm almost certain you must be using Python 3 otherwise you'd have had decoding errors.

Comment: @Hakaishin, Martijn Pieters is correct. I edited my answer accordingly.